# What is the difference between sunspot:solr:run and sunspot:solr:start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Running sunspot:solr:start raises the error

"This command is not supported on i386-mingw32. Use rake sunspot:solr:run to run Solr in the foreground."

Running sunspot:solr:run just hangs. What does run int the "foreground" mean?

**Edit**

How can one run solr:run and rails s?

Answer (score 5):

The `start` one runs it in the background as like a service running on the system, where `run` just runs it in the console (foreground) where you ctrl+c it to kill it.

Comment: so how can one run rails s & solr:run? since cntrl+C shuts them both down

Comment: Run them in different terminals

Answer (score 2):

*RUN*

Running in the foreground means that you will see in console the logging whenever a command is called. This is great in a development mode so you can see the system (re)indexing and pulling the queries. Useful for debugging.

*START*

Start will allow you to run it in the background as a service and is also helpful in production mode where you have the service running without need to be logged in with the console.

When running in production, you will want to do something like this

`RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:start`

Answer (score 0):

1. The `sunspot:solr:run`  runs the process in the console, in your terminal you can see it and you can stop it using `ctrl+c`
2. The `sunspot:solr:start` runs the process in the background and to stop the process you need to use `sunspot:solr:stop`, If you do not stop it explicitly then It will be terminated when you shutdown your machine.

**Note:** To get the accurate search result according to your current logic and code, use `rake sunspot:reindex` command after running the process using `sunspot:solr:run` or `sunspot:solr:start`

Answer (score 0):

Press

> 'ctrl+shift+t'

to open a new tab in existing opened terminal.